# Why is $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^{2}$ the cotangent space to a variety?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties, tangent-spaces

Let $X$ be a variety (or just a scheme) then for a point $p \in X$ with local ring $\mathcal{O}_{p}$ at $p$, we define the *cotangent* space at $p$ to be the $\kappa(p)$-vector space $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^{2}$, where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{p}$ and $\kappa(p)$ is the residue field at $p$.

But why? I cannot see the intuition behind this. The vector space $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^{2}$ is just the space of functions vanishing at $p$, modulo higher order terms. So in other words, first order approximations of functions vanishing at $p$.

All of my intuition tells me this is precisely what a *tangent* space is. So why is this the cotangent space? Why do we not then call the space of derivations the cotangent space?

I was tempted to say this was just a matter of convention, but most algebraic geometry books claim that the cotangent space is more natural, and suggest that this is a quirk of algebraic geometry as opposed to differential geometry. So this suggests it is not just a convention but that there is some real meaningful difference.

I am sorry if this is an extraordinarily basic question, but I find I am just going about using the definition without actually really knowing what or why I am doing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your intuition is not correct: a tangent vector at a point is something you can take a directional derivative along. This leads naturally to the identification of the tangent space with the derivations acting on local functions defined at our point by sending a direction to the derivative along that direction (one can check that this is reversible). In other words, if $X$ is a $C^\infty$ manifold with a point $p\in X$, then  $T_pX=\operatorname{Der}(\mathcal{O}_{X,p},\Bbb R)$.

If we do the same thing for a scheme, we get $T_pX=\operatorname{Der}(\mathcal{O}_{X,p},\kappa(p))$, and this is the dual of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ because a derivation can only see the linear term. Voila, the Zariski cotangent space!

Comment: Thank you @Kreiser for that answer, it is very helpful. And thank you for all the answers and patience you have shown with so many of my questions in the past.

I guess what I am still confused about is how this more sophisticated notion of "tangent space" corresponds to the naïve undergraduate multivariable calculus notion of "tangent space". There, a tangent space to, say, a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a plane that touches the surface at one point. Can we view the space of derivations as being an actual geometric plane (or linear space) somehow lying tangent to a variety?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure I have a great explanation at the ready for this - I mostly think of the (co)tangent space as being intrinsic and not embedded in the same place as the variety. Here's an attempt, though: if your variety is embedded in $\Bbb A^n$, you can ask for a linear subvariety which contains the point you care about and has the same tangent space, which corresponds to considering the linear space cut out by the functions with the same constant + linear terms as those in the ideal cutting out your variety.

Answer (score 2):

**Question:** "I am sorry if this is an extraordinarily basic question, but I find I am just going about using the definition without actually really knowing what or why I am doing it."

**Answer:** This is a much asked question by students: To "mod out" by the square of a maximal ideal corresponds to "taking derivatives".

**Example:**  If $A:=k[x,y]$ and $I:=(x-a,y-b)$ a maximal ideal with $p:=(a,b)\in k^2$, and $k$ a field, there is a canonical projection map

$$T^1: A \rightarrow A/I^2.$$

Any polynomial $f(x,y)\in A$ may be written as

$$f(x,y)=f(a,b)+ \partial_x(f)(p)(x-a)+\partial_y(f)(p)(y-b) +\cdots \in A.$$

You get a map

$$D: A \rightarrow I/I^2$$

defined by

$$D(f):=T^1(f)-f(p)=\partial_x(f)(p)(x-a)+\partial_y(f)(p)(y-b) \in k\{(x-a),(y-b)\}.$$

Hence the map $D$ takes the derivative of $f(x,y)$ at $p=(a,b)$.

**Note:** You find an elementary and more detailed answer to your question below. You also find a discussion of the tangent cone that may provide intuition. It explains why it is natural to define the tangent space as the dual of the cotangent space. Note that if $k \rightarrow A$ is any $k$-algebra and $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq A$ is a maximal ideal with residue field $k$, it follows the fiber

$$\Omega^1_{A/k}\otimes_A A/\mathfrak{m}\cong \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$$

is the cotangent space. Hence

"the cotangent space is the fiber of the cotangent module"

$\Omega^1_{A/k}$ at $k$-rational points.

**Example:** If $J \subseteq A\otimes_k A$ is the ideal of the diagonal, you may define $\Omega^1_{A/k}:=J/J^2$. The map $D$ defined above is the composed map

$$d: A \rightarrow J/J^2 \rightarrow J/J^2\otimes_A A/I \cong I/I^2$$

where $d: A\rightarrow \Omega^1_{A/k}:=J/J^2$ is the universal derivation:

$$d(f):=1\otimes f - f\otimes 1.$$

When $A$ is a regular $k$-algebra of finite type it follows $\Omega^1_{A/k}$ is a finite rank projective $A$-module: It is the "cotangent bundle" of $A/k$.

If $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is the local ring of $A$ at a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, there is an isomorphism of $A/\mathfrak{m}$-vector spaces

$$\mathfrak{m}_{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m}_{\mathfrak{m}}^2 \cong \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2,$$

hence the cotangent space can be defined in terms of the local ring of $A$ at $\mathfrak{m}$. The local ring is intrinsic and does not depend on a "choice of coordinates" and one wants to define the cotangent and tangent space independently of choice of coordinates. If you choose a closed embedding

$$\phi: Spec(A) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$$

into affine $n$-space (equivalently: You choose a set of coordinates of $A$), you may define the "embedded tangent space $E(x)$ of $Spec(A)$ at $x$" using the embedding. Then you must prove that $E(x)$ is independent of choice of embedding $\phi$. When using the local ring, you avoid this problem. See the attached links for more information:

[$aX + bY$ is an element of $M^2$ if and only if the line $aX + bY = 0$ is tangent to $W$ at $(0, 0)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155435/ax-by-is-an-element-of-m2-if-and-only-if-the-line-ax-by-0-is-tangen/4155994#4155994)

[About the definition of tangent space and tangent cone.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4125495/about-the-definition-of-tangent-space-and-tangent-cone)

[Dimension of the tangent space in algebraic geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4125818/dimension-of-the-tangent-space-in-algebraic-geometry)